# Build images as part of Jenkins Worker on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins

I have Jenkins deployed on kubernetes (AWS EKS), and a node designated for the jenkins pipelines tasks.
I have a pipeline which I want to build a docker image, so here is how my pipelines looks:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            defaultContainer 'jnlp'
            yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    illumex.ai/noderole: jenkins-worker
  containers:
  - name: docker
    image: docker:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
      name: docker-sock
  volumes:
  - name: docker-sock
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
"""
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                container('system') {
                        sh """
                        docker system prune -f
                        """
```

However, my job fails with:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I think it's permissions issue. However, since the containers are created as part of the pipeline, so for which user I should give permission?

Answer (score 0):

On your Jenkins machine, ensure docker is installed and the user jenkins is in the docker group.

Installing the docker plugin is not enough.
Same for kubectl must be installed on the Jenkins machine.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins 

ARG HOST_UID=1004
ARG HOST_GID=999

USER root
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add - && \
    add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") $(lsb_release -cs) stable" && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose  \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose  \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose \
    && curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - 
RUN echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list \
    && apt-get -y update \
    && apt install -y kubectl

RUN usermod -u $HOST_UID jenkins
RUN groupmod -g $HOST_GID docker
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins
FROM base
RUN kubectl version
USER jenkins
```

Comment: But my Jenkins is deployed on Kubernetes, So the Jenkins user is available only in the pod that created for the build task.

Comment: Create a custom image

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible from kubernetes 1.23:
https://community.jenkins.io/t/buildx-in-jenkins-agent-in-k8s-1-23/3013

Comment: just build the image as in my exampe and use it in your pod. No issue with 1.23. If you use however kubectl inside the pod you must create some rbac to authorize the pod to access kubernetes.

Comment: I will try, but I don't understand why it should work. My workers pods are running on a dedicated node and don't effected by the pod of jenkins itself.

Comment: When you execute a command in the pod where your jenkinsjob is running. In that ccontainer docket must be installed. Or you cant execute docker commands inside that container.